# malformed entry 1 in list error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

When I run `sudo apt upgrade` in my terminal, I have this message:

```
E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list (URI)

E: The list of sources could not be read.

E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list (URI)

E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

and when I do  `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list`

it prints this

```
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg]
https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Is `deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg]
https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main` actually two lines in that file? ... It should be one single line.